# Port 2121 is blocked but no application uses it

Tags: networking, port, windows-11

I'm using Windows 11 and want to start an application that uses local port 2121. But currently I always get the message that the port is already in use.

Even completely reduced examples in Java or Python do not work with this port.

A call of the command `netstat -aon | findstr 2121` shows no result, even executed as Administrator.

Also no application with CurrPorts can be found.

Is there another explanation why the port cannot be used although no other program occupies it?

Comment: Are you certain the application isn't already running?

Comment: FTP Proxy uses 2121, do you have a proxy running?

Comment: Try to disable temporarily the Windows firewall, and if that doesn't help then also your security software (if other than Windows Defender).

Comment: Even after a restart and with disabled windows Firewall the port is not working.
I don't have a proxy running and the application blocking the port should be displayed with the netstat command, but there seems to be nothing..

Comment: It's not clear, but are you trying to run a server or client locally? If client, where is the remote connection to?